# Get total height of a windows form including non-client area?

Tags: winforms

How to get the total height of a windows form including non-client area? Size does not seem to work for my window (FormBorderStyle = FixedToolWindow, if that helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the DesktopBounds property of the form.

Comment: If the `FormBorderStyle` is `FixedToolWindow`, then I don't think `DesktopBounds` gives a better answer than `Size`.  I think both will be incorrect if Aero is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The Size property should definitely work.  Beware that the form may be rescaled due to differences in the system font or the video adapter DPI setting between the design machine and the production machine.  The real size won't be available until the Load event.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will lie about the Form's size if Aero is enabled and your `FormBorderStyle` is `FixedToolWindow`.  I think the following code in a `Form` will give the correct height and width of such a Window.

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

// When Aero is enabled, and our FormBorderStyle is FixedToolWindow,
//    Windows will lie to us about our size and position.
public bool AeroIsMessingWithUs()
{
    bool ret = false;

    // check for other Fixed styles here if needed
    if (FormBorderStyle == System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow)
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 && DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
        {
            // Aero is enabled
            ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public int MyWindowHeight()
{
    int height = Height;
    if (AeroIsMessingWithUs())
    {
        // there are actually 5 more pixels on the top and bottom
        height += 10;
    }
    return height;
}

public int MyWindowWidth()
{
    int width = Width;
    if (AeroIsMessingWithUs())
    {
        // there are 5 more pixels on the left and right
        width += 10;
    }
    return width;
}
```